# Xib and Storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have two files xib and storyboard. In the xib file there is a custom menu for working with photos (brightness, saturation, etc.). Variable containing a photo is in ViewController. I created an @IBAction for each button in xib. How to transfer a photo to a xib file to work with it?

Toolbar.xib file: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S9Ffl.png)

Toolbar.swift:

`@IBAction func BrightnessButton(_ sender: Any) {
        // Use custom image from ViewController.swift
    }`

ViewController: `var customImage: UIImage?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work. You basically want to create a new UIImage variable inside the Toolbar class which gets set when you select an image inside your ViewController class.

ViewController.swift:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    ...
    var customImage: UIImage? {
        didSet {
           toolbar.image = customImage
        }
    }
    var toolbar: Toolbar!
    ...
}
```

Toolbar.swift:

```
class Toolbar {
   ...
   var image: UIImage?
   ...

   @IBAction func BrightnessButton(_ sender: Any) {
    // Use custom image from ViewController.swift
       guard let currentImage = image else {
           // we didn't set the image yet
           return
       }
       // make changes to your image here
   }
}
```